# Add bootstrap datatable to literal in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add bootstrap datatable to my project .
when i try the following code in source it works fine

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Rendering engine</th>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>Platform(s)</th>
        <th>Engine version</th>
        <th>CSS grade</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet
             Explorer 4.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center"> 4</td>
        <td class="center">X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even gradeC">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet
             Explorer 5.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">5</td>
        <td class="center">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd gradeA">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet
             Explorer 5.5</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">5.5</td>
        <td class="center">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even gradeA">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet
             Explorer 6</td>
        <td>Win 98+</td>
        <td class="center">6</td>
        <td class="center">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd gradeA">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
        <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
        <td class="center">7</td>
        <td class="center">A</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

At the same time when i try to do it from code behind, it fails

```
string table_contect = "<table cellpadding="+"\0\" cellspacing="+"\0\" border="+"\0\" class="+"\"table table-striped table-bordered table-hover\""+" id="+"\"example\'" +"><thead><tr><th>Rendering engine</th><th>Browser</th><th>Platform(s)</th><th>Engine version</th><th>CSS grade</th></tr></thead>";
        table_contect += " <tbody><tr class=" + "\"odd gradeX\""+ "><td>Trident</td><td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td><td>Win 95+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + "> 4</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">X</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"even gradeC\"" + ">";
        table_contect += "<td>Trident</td><td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td><td>Win 95+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">5</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">C</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"odd gradeA\"" + "><td>Trident</td><td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>";
        table_contect += "<td>Win 95+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">5.5</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"even gradeA\"" + "><td>Trident</td><td>Internet Explorer 6</td><td>Win 98+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">6</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td>";
        table_contect += "</tr><tr class=" + "\"odd gradeA\"" + "><td>Trident</td><td>Internet Explorer 7</td><td>Win XP SP2+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">7</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"even gradeA\"" + "><td>Trident</td><td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td><td>Win XP</td>";
        table_contect += "<td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">6</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"gradeA\"" + "><td>Gecko</td><td>Firefox 1.0</td><td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">1.7</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"gradeA\"" + "><td>Gecko</td><td>Firefox 1.5</td>";
        table_contect += "<td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">1.8</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"gradeA\"" + "><td>Gecko</td><td>Firefox 2.0</td><td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">1.8</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"gradeA\"" + "><td>Gecko</td>";
        table_contect += "<td>Firefox 3.0</td><td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">1.9</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"gradeA\"" + "><td>Gecko</td>";
        table_contect += "<td>Camino 1.0</td><td>OSX.2+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">1.8</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"gradeA\"" + "><td>Gecko</td><td>Camino 1.5</td><td>OSX.3+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">1.8</td>";
        table_contect += "<td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"gradeA\"" + "><td>Gecko</td><td>Netscape 7.2</td><td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">1.7</td>";
        table_contect += "<td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"gradeA\"" + "><td>Gecko</td><td>Netscape Browser 8</td><td>Win 98SE+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">1.7</td>";
        table_contect += "<td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"gradeA\"" + "><td>Gecko</td><td>Netscape Navigator 9</td><td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">1.8</td>";
        table_contect += "<td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td></tr><tr class=" + "\"gradeA\"" + "><td>Gecko</td><td>Mozilla 1.0</td><td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">1</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td>";
        table_contect += "</tr><tr class=" + "\"gradeA\"" + "><td>Gecko</td><td>Mozilla 1.1</td><td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">1.1</td><td class=" + "\"center\"" + ">A</td></tr></tbody></table>";
        //Response.Write(table_contect);
        Literal1.Text = table_contect;<br>
```

i got the table with rows not having header, filter textbox, pagination. Why this happens.

i am trying it in the same page itself.

Comment: friends, i got it its my  mistake. id="+"\"example\'" to be id="+"\"example\""..inattention..killed my time...sorry

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your first bit of string concatenation is invalid and wont produce the same output as you have shown earlier.  For example, this bit:

```
"<table cellpadding="+"\0\" cellspacing="+"\0\"...
```

Should read:

```
"<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"...
```

There's also quite a bit of unnecessary concatenation going on throughout.

If you want an accurate representation of what you're generating, it might be best to dump out the contents of `table_contect` whilst debugging.  If you're viewing the source from a browser, the browser will most likely try repair and make sense of badly structured HTML.  So this wont give an accurate picture of what HTML you are generating programmatically.

What advantages do you get building it programmatically in one big literal?  There is a `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable` that you could use to break it down and specify the rows, etc. separately.